# Подсчета статистики для временного ряда cсо смещением с группировкой по значению функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Возможно ли реализовать нижеприведенные требования на python + pandas без использования циклов? Интересует best practice использования возможностей библиотеки pandas.

Есть история торгов в виде массива данных. 
1) Требуется собрать статистику по кол-во c группировкой по значению функции Func(N(i+step)[high]/N(i)[open] >= threshold). Где step = 1, threshold = 1.005

Формат данных

```
[[open, high, low, close], ......, [open, high, low, close]]
```

Пример данных

```
[
  [10, 15, 3, 11],
  [12, 18, 4, 10],
  [9, 10, 6, 7],
  [8, 11, 1, 10],
  [11, 12, 3, 10],
  [6, 7, 3, 3],
  [4, 30, 4, 20],
]
```

Требуется подсчитать статистику
2) Статистика для 1) подсчитывается для разных значений step. Из полученных результатов требуется выбрать значение step с наибольшим значением count для Func = True.

Пример расчета значения функций для step = 1:

```
1) для первой пары 18/10 = 1.8 > 1.005 = True
2) для второй пары 20/12 = 0.83 > 1.005 = False 
3) для третьей пары 20/9 = 2.22 > 1.005 = True
```

Пример расчета значения функций для step = 2:

```
1) для первой пары 10/10 = 1 > 1.005 = False
2) для второй пары 20/12 = 1.66 > 1.005 = True 
3) для третьей пары 12/9 = 1.33 > 1.005 = True
```

Пример расчета выполненого в Excel. 
Зеленым цветом отмечены записи, которые должны учитываться при подсчете статистики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На выходе требуется отобразить статисику (3, 2, 0) по кол-ву выполнений условий функций, а также указать, что при значении step=1 резлуьтат имеет максимальное значение.

Comment: Какой датасет вы ожидаете получить на выходе?

Comment: С данной формулировкой вопроса непонятно что вы хотите получить на выходе. [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похоже в вопросе описание не соответствует примерам  - по-моему должно быть так:

```
0) первую строку DF пропускаем              => NaN
1) для второй строки 18/10 = 1.8 > 1.005    => True
2) для третьей строки 10/12 = 0.83 > 1.005  => False 
3) для четвертой строки 11/9 = 1.22 > 1.005 => True
4) для пятой строки 12/8 = 1.5 > 1.005      => True
5) для шестой строки 7/11 = 0.64 > 1.005    => False
6) для седьмой строки 30/6 = 5 > 1.005      => True
```

Если я правильно понял задачу - это можно сделать так:

```
def f(df, step=-1, thresh=1.005):
    return  (df['high'].shift(step) / df['open'] > thresh).shift(-step)

df['step_1'] = f(df, step=-1)
df['step_2'] = f(df, step=-2)
df['step_3'] = f(df, step=-3)
```

Получится (начиная со `step_2` - результаты отлисаются от ваших - проверьте правильно ли посчитали вручную):

```
In [51]: df
Out[51]:
   open  high  low  close step_1 step_2 step_3
0    10    15    3     11    NaN    NaN    NaN
1    12    18    4     10   True    NaN    NaN
2     9    10    6      7  False  False    NaN
3     8    11    1     10   True  False   True
4    11    12    3     10   True   True  False
5     6     7    3      3  False  False  False
6     4    30    4     20   True   True   True
```

дальше можно легко найти столбец с максимальной суммой:

```
In [53]: df.filter(like='step_').sum()
Out[53]:
step_1    4.0
step_2    2.0
step_3    2.0
dtype: float64

In [54]: df.filter(like='step_').sum().idxmax()
Out[54]: 'step_1'
```

чтобы не учитывать строки с `NaN`:

```
In [55]: df.dropna()
Out[55]:
   open  high  low  close step_1 step_2 step_3
3     8    11    1     10   True  False   True
4    11    12    3     10   True   True  False
5     6     7    3      3  False  False  False
6     4    30    4     20   True   True   True

In [56]: df.dropna().filter(like='step_').sum()
Out[56]:
step_1    3.0
step_2    2.0
step_3    2.0
dtype: float64

In [57]: df.dropna().filter(like='step_').sum().idxmax()
Out[57]: 'step_1'
```

Comment: В третьей строке замени 20 на 11. Я поменял значение и в исходном сообщении. Чтобы сравнение между step_ было равнозначным, нужно брать 4 последние строки.

Comment: Неожидал, что решение будет таким коротким

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, дополнил ответ